# Laravel PUT/PATCH request not getting the request payload

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, put, axios, laravel-5.5

I'm facing some issue with Laravel-vuejs/axios PUT and PATCH requests. Actually the PUT/PATCH request are working when I run the project in localhost. But when I tried the same project in hosting server, I don't know why only these two requests are not working. Remaining methods GET/POST/DELETE are working as expected. But when I perform PUT/PATCH request to my server, in my controller I'm not receiving any data sent from vue/axios request.

```
// axios request from vue component

export const updateItem = ({ commit, dispatch }, payload) => {
    return axios.put('items/' + payload.id, payload).then((response) => {
        return Promise.resolve(response)
    })
}

// Web Route

Route::put('/items/{item}', 'ItemController@update')->name('items.update');

//ItemController

public function update(Request $request, Item $item)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
    ]);

    try {
        $item->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
        ]);
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        return $e->errorInfo;
    }

    return response()->json($item, 200);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in your browser dev tools network tab? Are you getting any response error code at all?

Comment: @skribe as I'm not getting the data getting at the controller, I'm getting validation errors.

Comment: Can you post the error message here?

Comment: @skribe `{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"name":["The name field is required."],"price":["The price field is required."]}}`

Comment: What happens if you change the method to POST and add the field _method with the value PUT to your input fields? Depending on the server setup and headers PHP doesn't always handle PUT, PATCH or DELETE requests properly and doing that is a way to "fake" one of those HTTP verbs.

Comment: @MatthewDaly thanks, it is working with method spoofing, but what kind of setting should I modify to work with axios PUT/PATCH/DELETE?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: I imagine your web server may be configured to handle only GET or POST, or may be an older one that doesn't support anything else.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I'm using Apache

Comment: It's not method problem. If it was, laravel throws an exception before letting it enter the controller. So definitely is not method type. How you fill your payload??? I'm pretty sure something is wrong in your payload.

Comment: @train_fox Wrong. PHP doesn't always handle PUT or PATCH requests properly, and it's common to have problems with input fields for them. It's not an issue with Laravel, but the PHP language itself.

Comment: @e-Designary Maybe look at your Apache config and/or .htaccess to see if there's anything limiting the HTTP verbs it accepts

Comment: @e-Designary Usually this sort of problem happens when uploading files by PUT but as you aren't doing that I'd bet your Apache cconfig is the source of the problem. Can you add your .htaccess and Apache config files to the question?

Comment: @MatthewDaly I didn't say PHP can handle them. Actually PHP can just handle GET and POST. I said LARAVEL does support PUT, PATCH, DELETE and when your request goes inside controller it means LARAVEL handled request correctly.

Comment: @train_fox No, PHP can handle PUT, PATCH and DELETE as a general rule of thumb. The problems normally start if you try to send both files and input data in the same request via PUT or PATCH, and it's an issue at language level, not framework level. As OP isn't doing this and it works with the dev server I think it's an issue with how the production server is configured that can be bypassed by using method spoofing.